# How to use regexp_instr in Teradata such that start position of the search start at the end? Unlike INSTR its not taking -1 as position argument

Tags: regex, teradata, regex-group, teradatasql

How to use regexp_instr in Teradata such that start position of the search start at the end? Unlike INSTR its not taking -1 as position argument?I was trying to get the occurrence of a pattern from the end of a string. Unlike INSTR its not taking -1 as position argument.

Answer (score 0):

Regex does not work like that.  Instead, you ANCHOR your pattern to the end of the string with $.  So if you want all strings that end with XYZZY, your regex is XYZZY$.

**EDIT**
OP revealed that it is the position of the last alphanumeric character that is desired.  So, use regex to find one alphanumeric followed by an indefinite number of non-alphanumerics followed by the end of the string.

Using lowest common denominator regexp functions, alphanumeric is `[A-Za-z0-9]`, or, if we remember to turn on the "i" flag in the call we can shorten it to `[a-z0-9]`.  Similarly, a non-alphanumeric is `[^a-z0-9]`, and any possible number of them are `[^a-z0-9]*`.  Finally, the end of the string is `$`.  Putting it all together,

```
Regexp_instr(mytextcolumn,'[a-z0-9][^a-z0-9]*$',1,1,0,'i')
```

The zero arg returns the first position of the match.

Comment: I want to know the position of the last alphanumeric character in a string